# Problems with 'this': How do I access both an element and a class inside an addEvent function?

Tags: javascript, mootools, this

This is probably best explained through some code. I know that in the following example, the `this` inside the addEvent method is the current element contained in the array `elements`.

```
var testClass = new Class({
    testMethod: function() {
        var elements = $$('.elements');
        elements.addEvent('click', function() {
            console.log(this) //This will log the current element from elements
            });
        }
    });
```

I also know that in the following example, `this` instead refers to the class `testClass` because I have utilised the bind method.

```
var testClass = new Class({
    testMethod: function() {
        var elements = $$('.elements');
        elements.addEvent('click', function() {
            console.log(this); //This will log the class testClass
            }.bind(this));
        }
    });
```

My question, then, is how do I access both the class and the current element at the same time in addEvent?

Please note that if elements were not an array, this would not be problematic as I could pass elements as a parameter in the bind method. However, as it is an array, I cannot do this as it would simple give me an array of all the elements instead of the current element. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide an argument event argument to your event handler function, for example:

```
var TestClass = new Class({
  testMethod: function() {
    var elements = $$('.elements');
    elements.addEvent('click', function(e) {
      console.log(this);     // the object instance
      console.log(e.target); // <--- the HTML element
    }.bind(this));
  }
});
```

MooTools will pass a normalized [event object](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/Event) as the `e` argument of your event handler function, there you can access the `e.target` property which will refer to the DOM element that triggered the event.

Comment: Ah yes that does it! You legend! Thanks :).

Comment: Note that `e.target` is not guaranteed to be an element in `$$('.elements')`. It may be a descendant child instead, since `click` bubbles.

Comment: @Crescent, yeah, I should be more explicit in my last line. Glad to see you back around :)

Comment: to avoid the bubbling issue, your only guarantee is to fix it upriver - do the .each loop on the elements manually which will give you an element token you can refer to: `elements.each(function(el) { el.addEvent('click', function(e) { console.log(el); }.bind(this); }, this);`